# Iterate through a dictionary with React to construct a Table

Tags: reactjs

I want to iterate a dictionary to construct a table using React, but I am stuck with this error:

> PricingPlanTable.jsx:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map'
>   of undefined

Here's my code:

**BillingAccount.jsx**

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import PricingPlanTable from './PricingPlanTable';

export default class BillingAccount extends React.Component {
    render() {

        var pricingPlans = {
            'planNames': ['Starter', 'Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Enterprise'],
            'planPrices': ['free', '$10', '$25', '$49', 'Contact Us'],
            'planOptions': [
                {'option': 'A', 'values': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']},
                {'option': 'B', 'values': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']},
                {'option': 'C', 'values': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']}

            ]
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <PricingPlanTable table={pricingPlans}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**PricingPlanTable.jsx**

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

export default class PricingPlanTable extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const table = this.props.table.map((table, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Starter</th>
                                <th>Bronze</th>
                                <th>Silver</th>
                                <th>Gold</th>
                                <th>Enterprise</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>free</td>
                                <td>19€ /mo</td>
                                <td>79€ /mo</td>
                                <td>190€ /mo</td>
                                <td>custom</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            )})
        return (
             <div>
                {table}
             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**This is a mockup of what I am trying to achieve:**
[image: This is a mockup of what I am trying to achieve]

The **PricingPlanTable.jsx** has the table hardcoded but I am trying to use the 'this.props' functionality of React to iterate through it. I would like to use a skeleton of the template and populate it with the pricingPlans var from the **BillingAccount.jsx** file.

Comment: where are you passing table as a prop? I see that you are passing pricingTable, not table

Comment: Good point, my mistake while passing the question to here. But in my file I already am passing table. Still, sends this error: PricingPlanTable.jsx:33 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.table.map is not a function

Comment: That's because pricingplans is an object and you can't map over an object. You must map over an array.

Comment: I see, yep, that's the case. Also, as we speak, I changed my const planOptions to const planOptions = this.props.table.planOptions.map((table, i) and now I can iterate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

pricingPlans that you are passing as a prop is an object and cannot be iterated over. You would need to access each object within pricing plans since they actually contain an array and iterate over them.

Please look at the following documenatation on how to use Array.map() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

So with your current data structure you could do something like the following :

```
createHeaders() {
  this.props.table.planNames.map((plan) => {
    return <th>{plan}</th>
  });
}

createContent() {
  this.props.table.planPrices.map((price) => {
    return <tr>{price}</tr>
  });
}

render() {

  const table = this.props.table;

  return(
    <table>
      <tr>
        {this.createHeaders}
      </tr>
      <tr>
        {this.createContent}
      </tr>
    </table>
  )
}
```

Comment: I understand, thanks. As I was trying to get it work, I got this warning although: warning.js:45 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <table>. See PricingPlanTable > table > tr. Add a <tbody> to your code to match the DOM tree generated by the browser.

And with it, nothing was rendered.

Comment: Ok, i got that. I wrapped the elements in a <tbody></tbody> and the warning is no more. Although... nothing renders so far, just a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should use an array with map.Use map in planOptions instead. Secondly in map you are returning the table again and again rather you must return only rows. This is what it should be like.

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

export default class PricingPlanTable extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const table = this.props.table.planOptions.map((obj, i) => {
            return (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{obj.option}</td>
                {obj.value.map(value => {
                return (
                  <td>{value}</td> 
                );
              })}
              </tr>
            )})
        return (
             <div>
          <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Starter</th>
                                <th>Bronze</th>
                                <th>Silver</th>
                                <th>Gold</th>
                                <th>Enterprise</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>free</td>
                                <td>19€ /mo</td>
                                <td>79€ /mo</td>
                                <td>190€ /mo</td>
                                <td>custom</td>
                            </tr>
                            {tbody}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.